# It is possible to check if import is wrong? while writing a custom rule

Tags: java, sonarqube

I would like to write a java rule Will generate a issue if an imported class is an APIClass annotation and the imported class has issues. I am following [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101) tutorial.

The code:

First, I wrote a simple rule:

```
@Rule( key = "ForbidClassVariables", name = "ForbidClassVariables")
public class ForbidClassVariables extends BaseTreeVisitor implements JavaFileScanner {

private JavaFileScannerContext context;

@Override
public void scanFile(JavaFileScannerContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    if (context.getSemanticModel() != null) {
        scan(context.getTree());
    }       
}

@Override
public void visitClass(ClassTree tree) {
    if (tree.modifiers().annotations().size() > 0 && hasAnnotation(tree.modifiers().annotations(), "APIClass")) {
        if (hasClassVariables(tree)) {
            this.context.reportIssue(this, tree.simpleName(), "Do not use class variables on API Classes.");
        }
    }
    super.visitClass(tree);
}

private boolean hasAnnotation(List<AnnotationTree> annotations, String annotationName) {
    for (AnnotationTree annotation : annotations) {
        if (annotation.annotationType().is(Tree.Kind.IDENTIFIER)
                && ((IdentifierTree) annotation.annotationType()).name().equals(annotationName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean hasClassVariables(ClassTree tree) {
    for (Tree member : tree.members()) {
        if (member.is(Tree.Kind.VARIABLE)) {
            VariableTree variableTree = (VariableTree) member;
            Symbol symbol = variableTree.symbol();
            if (!symbol.isStatic() || !symbol.isFinal()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

I created a test class file ExampleA.java

```
package br.com.test;

@APIClass
public class ExampleA {
    private String name;
}
```

When I run the test, generates an error on line 4, It was as expected.

**The point of the problem:** I created another rule:

```
@Rule( key = "CheckIFClassIsOK", name = "CheckIFClassIsOK")
public class CheckIFImportedClassIsOK  extends BaseTreeVisitor implements JavaFileScanner{

private JavaFileScannerContext context;

@Override
public void scanFile(JavaFileScannerContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    if (context.getSemanticModel() != null) {
        scan(context.getTree());
    }       
}

@Override
public void visitImport(ImportTree tree) {
    IdentifierTree identifier = ((MemberSelectExpressionTree) tree.qualifiedIdentifier()).identifier();

    System.out.println(identifier); // Shows ExampleA

    // At this point I need re-scan ExampleA class and IF the scan generate any issue
    // Will generate another here Issue on ExampleB

    super.visitImport(tree);
}   
}
```

And used this file to test:

```
import br.com.test.ExampleA;

public class ExampleB {

    private ExampleA exampleA;

}
```

The problem is, when I am visiting an import, if the imported class has an APIClass annotation and has issues, it will generate an issue on ExampleB.java to avoid using this import because has an issue. I have searched a lot on the Tree classes, but I didn't find anything useful. I think I need to force the re-scan on ExampleA.java, but how? Anyone have ideas?

Sonar version: 6.2
Java plugin version: 4.5.0.8398

Thanks for attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. There is no way in the API to request parsed tree from another file. However you are able to retrieve semantic information about members in class `ExampleB`, but this doesn't include annotations.

Comment: Thank you Tibor! Do you know another method I can do this? using another source code analyser for example?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know other analyzers well enough to advice anything. We do plan to have cross-compilation unit analysis in SonarJava, but I can't promise anything more concrete for the time being.